# Facebook self vCard

Tags: facebook, xmpp, vcf-vcard

Hi I want to get profile picture of my own. So After login, I am sending below IQ packet and getting the below mentioned response but it does not contain any Picture details.

Can anyone please help me what is the reason.

Reguest:

```
<iq to='-100002643606171@chat.facebook.com' from='' id='v1111'  type='get' xmlns='jabber:client'>
<vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'/>
</iq>
```

Response:

```
<iq id="v1111" to="XXXXXX@chat.facebook.com/8hAKe3RdK1_51d153db_4AFBBB1DF508F" from="-100002643606171@chat.facebook.com" type="result">
<vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'>
<FN>Req Lee</FN>
</vCard>
</iq>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get your own vCard, you should leave out the `to` attribute, or set it to your bare JID, like `to="XXXXXX@chat.facebook.com"`.

```
<iq type="get" id="myvcardplz">
 <vCard xmlns="vcard-temp"/>
</iq>
```